# Create TVirtualTable via Code only without drop component

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, devart

Recently i want to export data using TscExcelExport.
If i'm using TVirtualTable using Design Component, it works perfectly.

```
EmpVT.First;
EmpVT.Filtered := False;
while not EmpVT.Eof do
  begin
    //Salary Virtual Table
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.Append;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('EMPID').AsInteger := EmpVT.FieldByName('EMPID').AsInteger;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('EMPBANKGROUPNO').AsInteger := EmpVT.FieldByName('BANKGROUPNO').AsInteger;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('EMPTRANSBANKACCNAME').AsString := EmpVT.FieldByName('EMPBANKACCNAME').AsString;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('EMPTRANSBANKACCNO').AsString := EmpVT.FieldByName('EMPBANKACCNO').AsString;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('BANKACCNO').AsString := EmpVT.FieldByName('BANKACCNO').AsString;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('PERIOD').AsString := PaySlipPeriod;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('BANKNAME').AsString := EmpVT.FieldByName('BANKNAME').AsString;
        VirtualTableBankTransferList.FieldByName('TRANSFERAMOUNT').AsInteger := 0;//Format('%s%s%.*d', [EmpVT.FieldByName('REGIONCODE').AsString,EmpVT.FieldByName('EMPCODE').AsString,4,EmpVT.FieldByName('EMPCODE').AsInteger]); //EmpVT.FieldByName('EMPCODE').AsString;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('BANKID').AsString := EmpVT.FieldByName('BANKID').AsString;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('TBANKNAME').AsString := EmpVT.FieldByName('TBANKNAME').AsString;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.FieldByName('BANKLOCATION').AsString := EmpVT.FieldByName('BANKLOCATION').AsString;
    VirtualTableBankTransferListExport.Post;
    EmpVT.Next;
  end;
  scExcelExport1.WorksheetName := 'Bank Transfer List';
  scExcelExport1.Dataset:=VirtualTableBankTransferListExport;
  scExcelExport1.ExportDataset;
  scExcelExport1.Disconnect;
```

What is the correct way to create TVirtualTable via Code only without dropping TVirtualTable in form?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Install CnWizards (more features but less stable) or GExperts IDE (more polished but less features) add-on

They both have "Component-To-Code" wizard.

So you would select your component, run this command from the menu and would get the pure Pascal sources of creating it.

PS. Actually there might be several components, not a single one: fields are usually components of their own.